# Alternative to Hash and Salt for a Social Security/Government ID Number

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, hash, salt

I have a form that takes a social security number, and I need write code that checks if it has been entered within the last two days. All this is easy.

My current plan is to create a table `ssn_hash(id, ssn_hash, date)` and hash/salt the the ssn, then INSERT them into database. After that, create a view that displays the lasts two days. The salt being some other user data taken from the form.

I would like to know 2 things:

1. Is this a good approach? Or is there some other common practice that will achieve the same result.
2. Under PHP, is the only option from the std library the crypt() function?

Comment: Alternative to crypt? sha command?

Comment: PHP doesn't seem to have a `sha()` command, and `sha1()` doesn't allow me to specify the salt. For other things that would be fine, but I was hoping on a per user salt.

Answer (score 1):

`crypt` is perfectly fine with the following caveats:

- If you use user data as a salt, you severely limit its randomness.  Opt for something like `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` instead.
- Don't be afraid to store the salt in the table.  In fact `attr_encrypted`, a popular Ruby on Rails gem does this.  Just make sure you generate a unique salt for each entry.  Never reuse a salt.
- Make sure you don't use a broken encryption method like DES or SHA-1.  You can specify `CRYPT_BLOWFISH` or `CRYPT_SHA512`.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Why is storing the salt in the database not a security risk.

Comment: Great question, check out [this excellent answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17421/how-to-store-salt)

Comment: That was a really good post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Password encryption functions won't help you here if you need to do a quick look-up to see if the number has been used. Instead you'll have to go with a straight SHA1-type hash so you can do a reverse lookup.

You'll want to be absolutely certain your server is secured properly. Purging data from this table on a regular basis is probably a good idea as well.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the encryption wouldn't be helpful. In this case, only the encrypting function needs to know the ssn and salt, I don't and the application doesn't. Is it a bad idea to regenerate the hashed number every time I query the database?

Comment: The problem with a salt is each time it changes, so determining if SSN *x* is in the database becomes a case of scanning through each row and testing vs. the given *x* parameter. If you just hash, it becomes a quick look-up, match or no match.